# Is my installed RAM x8 or x16?

Tags: memory

Bought a new laptop, Vivobook x512FA, I need to know if my preinstalled 4GB RAM is x8 or x16 because I want to buy another bank of RAM, how can I know that?

UPDATE: I asked to the Asus technical support and they replied that those information are reserved... I don't have any words...

Comment: It would be in the documentation of the system.

Comment: Look at the sticker on the RAM stick. It will say 1RX8, 2RX8, 1RX16 or 2RX16 on it. If it doesn't have a sticker, count the chips on it. 4 chips = x16. 8 chips = x8.

Comment: Open the back of your laptop and tell us what the model number of the ram is.

Comment: The problem is that the preinstalled RAM is hidden somewhere, and I don't want to damage nothing. Here is a pic https://ibb.co/vPNggBk I think is under that black plastic thing at the bottom-right, but is it possible that if I unmount that I will have to reapply the thermal paste?

Comment: The populated RAM slot is probably on the other side.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's x8.

Comment: thank you David, I will buy an x8 RAM then, I don't have other choices

Answer (score 1):

You can find info about your RAM (ranks)  using HWInfo, under Module Characteristics, there is a property: `Device witdh`
x8 or x16.  I can confirm it works, just 2 days ago i've upgraded my 2x8GB x16 memory to 2x16GB x8 (Crucial).
[image]